# get access to data-grid result through add-in

Tags: sql-server-2008, add-in, ssms

I want to create an add-in for SQL Management studio that basically will give users ability to select a result from data-grid and save in specific format. This means I need to display few menu options via context menu when user right click on result in data-grid from query result set.

I have found some samples of how to do it but all those provide menu option from top menu items (like `Tools`) but didn't find anything so that I can get ability to get access to data-grid (for creating context menu items).

**Can someone provide any sample on how to do it?**